# Disable navigationitem backbarbutton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

How do I disable the backbutton in a navigationcontroller?

When I hide the button like so,
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
the buttonarea is still tappable.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  File a bug report! http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I'll file that.
I thought it might have something to do with setting it to TRUE, but the same thing happened with setting YES.

Comment: TRUE and YES should be the same :)
`#define YES             (BOOL)1`
`#define NO              (BOOL)0`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't need a back button and since part of navigationBar's existence is to have a back button you can simply hide the navBar. I can post the code to that if you want as Im doing that in couple of projects. Otherwise have your "bug" might not be a bug if you are calling it from the wrong place.
After digging i managed to come up with this.
To hide the back button use:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

To hide the whole navigationBar use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

But this will happen without animation, to animate it use this instead:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

This will make a sliding animation together with the navigation view. You will need to provide some other means for the person to get back tho.

Comment: Good thing about hiding the navBar is that after you finished parsing you can unhide it with animation and you will get a nice sliding animation from the top =)